# How to connect multiple LoRa devices with LoRa master node on STM32 sector?

Tags: c, multithreading, loops, stm32, lora

I'm struggling with the multiple device connection to the master device. How to handle the connection timeouts to the slave devices. "LoRa module SX1278 ISM-410-525MHz". It is perfectly working for one to one connections. But i have struggle on logic, for connecting multiple slave devices.

Easy to connect one device. But harder to connect more than one device if wake up on the same time.

> Here, I have attached the code. LoRa module SX1278. And used STM32CubeIde for code

```
 if (atoi(msg_id) < 11){

            responce = SX1278_LoRaEntryRx(&SX1278, 16, 2000);
            HAL_Delay(500);
            responce = SX1278_LoRaRxPacket(&SX1278);

          if (responce > 1 && responce < 10 ){

                  SX1278_read(&SX1278,(uint8_t*)RXDATA, responce);
                  memcpy(RXDATA, strl, sizeof(RXDATA));
                  HAL_Delay(2000);
                  count1 ++;
                  if(count1 == 1){
                        count1 = 0;
                        loop_count += 1;
                        if(Uart_first != 1){
                            HAL_UART_Init(&huart1);
    }
                  ConnectPacket();
  }
}
```